# What does the questionmark in subs or function-parameters mean?

Tags: vb.net, function

Just found it in an ado.net SQL-Insert command.

```
Public Sub a(b as Date?)
   'Somecode
End Sub
```

What exactly does this questionmark?

Comment: This denotes a [Nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx) type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Filburt alludes to, a parameter with a question mark denotes a [Nullable Value Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235245.aspx)

Please note, that you can only use this approach for datatypes that are indeed Nullable. Strings, for example, can not be used in this way.

```
Public Sub a(s As String?)
    'Some code 
End Sub
```

Will produce the following compilation error

> Type 'String' must be a value type or a type argument constrained to 'Structure' in order to be used with 'Nullable' or nullable modifier '?'.

**DataTypes that can be made Nullable**

- bool
- byte
- char
- decimal
- double
- enum
- float
- int
- long
- sbyte
- short
- struct
- uint
- ulong
- ushort

Comment: Nice to know. Thanks to you and @Filburt

Comment: Guess the `b as Date?` was a terrible codeexample by me then, since `DateTime` can't be NULL as well.

Comment: Technically yes, but the question is still valid. It must be a Value type as opposed to a Reference type. Reference types such as `String` and `DateTime` can just be set to `Nothing`, whereas doing this on a Value type will just set it to its default value.

Comment: @AFriend : A `DateTime` isn't nullable by default, it's a value type.

Comment: @DanielShillcock : Calling the list, or the items in the list, for "nullable types" may cause confusion. They _can be made_ nullable, but they aren't nullable by default. They're so-called _Value types_ (structures), which always has a value. Only _Reference types_ (classes) are nullable by default. -- Also, `Date` or `DateTime` is part of the list as well.